# Mongoid multiple atomic operations

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a kind of `Mongoid::Document` in memory. I want to atomically `inc` and `push` in the same call. `Mongoid::Criteria` only exposes these operations individually.

`my_model = SomeModel.find "foo"`

Bad:

```
my_model.inc foo: 1
my_model.push bar: "b"
```

Good:

`my_model.underlying_adapter.update "$inc" => {foo: 1}, "$push" => {bar: "b"}`

The question is, how do I access that underlying adapter for a single instance of a `Mongoid::Document`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use moped (the ruby adapter which mongoid uses) directly for this and other complex atomic operations which you want to achieve in a single query:

```
SomeModel.collection.find("_id" => "foo").update({
            '$inc' => {"foo" => 1},
            '$push' => {"bar" => "b"}})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you mean by atomically? timeless and without validation?

```
your_model.inc_field = your_model.inc_field + inc_value
your_model.push_field << pushable
your_model.timeless.save(validate: false)
```

P.S : Mongoid `inc` and `push` (and almost all other atomic operations) are at least 2 database hits (one read and one update).

---

**Edit**

If you want more advance query and command execution with mongoid you can use Moped (Mongoid uses Moped)

[Moped driver documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/moped/docs/driver.html)

---

**Edit 2**

It's limitation of mongoid (until current stable release - 3.1.6), refer to this [issue](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/1344) - In version 4 of mongoid (not released yet) user can do single write operation atomically (and also chainable) [Mongoid Changelog ISSUE#1344](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400)

From your code, I see you have model in memory it's at least 2 DB hit, 1 for read and 1 for write (even with chained atomic operations), Mongoid4 fixed that (1 DB hit with a single atomic operation, e.g : `Band.where(name: "Depeche Mode").inc(likes: 10, followers: 20)` or with `document.atomically &:block` syntax)

All write operations in MongoDB are atomic on the level of a single document. [MongoDB Docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-operations/)

Comment: why do you say that Mongoid doesn't perform atomic operations (2 database hits) - they are exactly the same single atomic update as they would be in native driver.  See http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/persistence.html

Comment: This is the database hits (log) : 
`MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY  database=awd_development collection=lists selector={"$query"=>{"active"=>true}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>-1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.4566ms)  ****  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 UPDATE       database=awd_development collection=lists selector={"_id"=>"529c5555421aa94c3e000012"} update={"$inc"=>{"todo"=>1}} flags=[] (0.1080ms)
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)`

Comment: Check the code [github/mongoid/mongoid/persistable/incrementable.rb](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/persistable/incrementable.rb)

Comment: Atomically as in the database will execute the command as a single unit of work and all will succeed or none will succeed (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems))

Comment: *1* : It's limitation of mongoid, refer to [this issue](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/1344), *2* : You have in memory so what's the real purpose of atomic operation?! *3* : `All write operations in MongoDB are atomic on the level of a single document.` [MongoDB Docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-operations/)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a ruby expert, but maybe you can use [find_and_modify](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#find_and_modify-instance_method)

Comment: That would work fine and would be a great solution if I didn't already have the object in memory, as it stands it would be an extra query and it wouldn't actually update the in-memory object.